# Should I inherit from Arduino's Stream or Print when I'm using write?

Tags: arduino, c++

I'm submitting a pull request to an Arduino library and want to make sure I'm doing the right thing before I send it. The change allows the dumping of data somewhere other than into a string buffer (in my case sending it to SRAM).

I've implemented this initially by altering the library  to take a Stream object which it will call write on when it's saving data (if the object has been passed). This seemed the most sensible as it's a stream of data.

However, when implementing my SRAM storage class I realised Stream has no write method, and I was pulling in 'using Print::write' to my class to give it that ability. Which made me think maybe I should have modified the library to take a Print object rather than a Stream object, as there's no guarantee a Stream will have a write method.

Would appreciate advice - Print seems wrong as the class, but the API style guide at http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/APIStyleGuide seems to suggest Stream as the way to go though it seems to imply that Stream implements write.

Comment: If `Stream` extends `Print`, and `Print` declares `write`, then any instance of `Stream` will also include an implementation of `write`. If all you want to do is use/override/... `write` then you should use `Print`, because then your code will work with both `Print` and `Stream`, as `Stream` *is a* `Print`.

Comment: Of course it is! Thank you @HannoBinder I should have seen this.

Comment: @HannoBinder if you convert your comment into an answer we can consider that the OP accepted it.